# How to do calculation using local macros

Tags: stata, stata-macros

In Stata I am looping over `i` and inside the loop, I want to get `i-1`. This is what I tried:

```
forvalues i = 2/10{
    local j `i' - 1
    drop if view`j' = 0
}
```

However, the `j` is actually 2-1 instead of 1.

If I use `` display("`j'") ``, I will get 2-1. So I am not able to do calculations using my local `i` this way.

Is there any way to get the result of `i' - 1 in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use assignment ("=" sign):

```
local i 1
di "`i'"
local j = `i' + 1
di "`j'"
```

Note that the proper terminology is "local macro". The term "variable" is reserved to refer to the variables in the dataset.

Comment: For an expansion of your last comment, see e.g. https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-08/msg01258.html

Comment: I edited out the reference to local variables in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

As @SultanOrazbayev pointed out, you are missing the difference between

```
local j `i' - 1
```

which copies a text string like `2 - 1` to the local macro and

```
local j = `i' - 1
```

which assigns text like `1` to the local macro.

See e.g. https://www.stata.com/manuals/u18.pdf for a basic introduction to local macros.

On the information in the question, the loop should just be rewritten

```
forvalues j = 1/9 {
    drop if view`j' == 0 
}
```

noting that `==` not `=` is the required syntax.

Comment: Oops, I didn't spot the "==" vs "=" part.

Comment: OP didn't provide an MRE for anyone to try their code. More positively, every good pair of eyes can see a different bug.